Creating a specific gradient in css that has transparency
I have a gradient I'm trying to make in CSS. I added the Figma settings and an image of the gradient.
This is the code I tried and didn't get what i expected:


body {
  background-color: #000;
}
.circle {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: radial-gradient(circle, rgba(118, 60, 172, 1.00) 0%, rgba(50, 15, 133, 0) 100%);
}
<div class="circle"></div>





what was my mistake and how can i create the gradient i want?

Your gradient circle is overlayed on top of a dark background - what do you think transparency is going to do?

no, i'm just trying to do that effect like in the image, of this bright in the middle and transparent at the edges elipse

Oh, I thought that was a rendering of the CSS gradient. You need to edit your post to include a screenshot of how the CSS looks in your browser.

Change the 100% to another value 50% so it will automatically become transparent at 100%

The CSS gradient in the HTML snippet - and the Figma screesnhot of the radial gradient, look identical to me (in terms of color and gradient appearance). FWIW.

radial-gradient() settings
The order must be followed, but it's not mandatory to specify every parameter. Therefore, I marked the default values in bold in the list.

shape: circle | elipse
size:

closest-side | farthest-side | closest-corner | farthest-corner
or can use unique values with {width} {height}


position: at {x} {y} | at 50% 50%

It seems like you primarily want to create a circle centered in the middle, so using the circle shape and the at 50% 50% position might be appropriate, as I've incorporated into my examples.
Depending on the size value, you'll need to set the colors accordingly.
In the case of radial gradients, the default size value is farthest-corner.
Therefore, it will stretch the size to the farthest-corner, thus unfortunately causing the coloring to touch the edge of the div in every case. If you stick with this, as shown in my first example, I've also indicated that applying the final color earlier should prevent this.
Perhaps a better solution is my second and third examples, where I aligned the size to the side instead of the corner, allowing the coloring to extend to the shortest or longest side of the container.
With circle shape
Just leave a little space for the radial gradient, so it doesn't end at 100%, but sooner.


body {
  background-color: rgb(20, 7, 39);
}

.circle {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: radial-gradient(
    circle at 50% 50%,           /* [shape: circle | elipse] [size: closest-side | farthest-side] [position: at {x} {y}] -> not all required */
    rgba(118, 60, 172, 1.00) 0%,
    rgba(50, 15, 133, 0) 70%     /* or just use transparent 70% */
  );
}
<div class="circle"></div>



With closest-side size

The gradient's ending shape meets the side of the box closest to its center (for circles) or meets both the vertical and horizontal sides closest to the center (for ellipses).

In this case, it can remain at the original 100%.


body {
  background-color: rgb(20, 7, 39);
}

.circle {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: radial-gradient(
    circle closest-side at 50% 50%, /* [shape: circle | elipse] [size: closest-side | farthest-side] [position: at {x} {y}] -> not all required */
    rgba(118, 60, 172, 1.00) 0%,
    rgba(50, 15, 133, 0) 100%       /* or just use transparent 100% */
  );
}
<div class="circle"></div>



With farthest-side size

Similar to closest-side, except the ending shape is sized to meet the side of the box farthest from its center (or vertical and horizontal sides).



body {
  background-color: rgb(20, 7, 39);
}

.circle {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: radial-gradient(
    circle farthest-side at 50% 50%, /* [shape: circle | elipse] [size: closest-side | farthest-side] [position: at {x} {y}] -> not all required */
    rgba(118, 60, 172, 1.00) 0%,
    rgba(50, 15, 133, 0) 100%        /* or just use transparent 100% */
  );
}
<div class="circle"></div>



Use multiple (stacked) radial-gradient()
I created two separate radial-gradients with the two colors provided in your code, so the result may resemble the original color more closely.
There's no need to add transparency to it, as we are transitioning both colors towards completely transparent. Therefore, gradually both colors will become transparent. Additionally, I set the background color to a lilac similar to yours, because due to transparency, the background color of the body also influences the result


body {
  background-color: rgb(20, 7, 39);
}

.circle {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background:
    radial-gradient(
      closest-side,
      rgb(118, 60, 172),
      transparent
    ),
    radial-gradient(
      closest-side,
      rgb(50, 15, 133),
      transparent
    );
}
<div class="circle"></div>



More information

radial-gradient() - MDN Docs


hello, thank you very much it works, but its still different from the figma for some reason.

@Someone I've set a black background color. Perhaps yours might have a lilac shade. Besides, I'm not sure how Figma handles a color with 0 transparency. In theory, the color code should be irrelevant there, so in my interpretation, the second color would be transparent 70%.

Don't use circle but define the radii values to be equal to 50%. You can also omit the percentage of the color stops.


body {
  background-color: #000;
}
.circle {
  width: 300px;
  aspect-ratio:1;
  background: radial-gradient(50% 50%, rgb(118 60 172), #0000);
}
<div class="circle"></div>



